# looking for solution in WordPress-Developing

Tags: php, wordpress, web, dashboard

[WordPress dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6T4c.png)

is there are any easy way to make a employee login web site for WordPress Dashboard ?

- any Application programming interface[API] solutions?, any Content Management System[CMS] solution?

because giving access to main website back end for company data entering employees are too risky. And they are additionally try out some major updates stupidly. then i wanna solution for preventing that incident.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question to be more readable.

Comment: you can hide unnecessary menu from admin panel by settings user role capabilities, so that they are unable to access that menu. Please see this plugin User Role Editor https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what user roles are for: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Do not give administrator access to anyone who does not need it. Users with 'Editor' or 'Author' roles can add posts without being able to update Wordpress or plugins.